# django aws ses boto3 - why different IAM credentials are used for verify_email_identity

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses

I am trying to use django boto3 aws ses to to send email. I notice verify_email_identity uses a different IAM credentials, where is this set actually ? i didnt set it in my django app.

```
    client = boto3.client('ses', region_name='us-east-1') 
    client.verify_email_identity(EmailAddress="bounce@example.com") -> IAM user B

    conn = mail.get_connection('django_amazon_ses.EmailBackend') -> IAM user A
    email = EmailMessage(
        'Subject', 'Content', 'bounce@example.com', ['to@example.com'],
        headers={'From': 'from@example.com'},
    )
    self.assertGreater(conn.send_messages([email]), 0) -> IAM user A
```

IAM user A has all the permission (like below), but IAM user B doesnt have. to me its strange why it is using IAM user B, how can that be possible ? i checked all my code there is no such settings for IAM user B

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail",
                "ses:VerifyEmailIdentity"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In settings.py, this is IAM user A credentials, i didnt not set IAM user B in anywhere in the app, maybe somewhere else in the mac pc, but im not sure.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
```

The question is client = boto3.client and verify_email_identity sets the aws credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `django_amazon_ses` backend is designed for Django. Therefore it [can fetch credentials from your settings](https://github.com/azavea/django-amazon-ses#django-configuration).

When you use `boto3.client()` directly, it doesn't know about your Django settings. It tries to [fetch your credentials from several places](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html).

If you want to use the credentials from your Django settings, you can explicitly use them when instantiating the boto3 client:

```
s3_client = boto3.client(
    'ses', 
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY, 
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY, 
    region_name='us-east-1',
)
```